# Compiling GMP/MPFR with Emscripten

Tags: javascript, gmp, emscripten, mpfr, asm.js

Alright, this has been driving me insane. I've been trying this for at least a month, and no where on the internet is helping.

I followed the steps of [this](https://github.com/kripken/gmp.js). Not even the example works when I do these steps, because when I do it, I get this.

```
bitcode ==> javascript
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_cmp
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_mul_ui
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_submul_ui
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_init_set_ui
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_mul_2exp
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_init
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_fdiv_qr
warning: unresolved symbol: __gmpz_add
```

And when I run the resulting complete.js file -

```
missing function: __gmpz_init
-1
-1

/home/ubuntu/workspace/gmp.js/complete.js:117
      throw ex;
      ^
abort(-1) at Error
    at jsStackTrace (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gmp.js/complete.js:1045:13)
    at stackTrace (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gmp.js/complete.js:1062:22)
    at abort (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gmp.js/complete.js:6743:44)
    at ___gmpz_init (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gmp.js/complete.js:1744:56)
    at Object._main (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gmp.js/complete.js:4978:2)
    at Object.callMain (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gmp.js/complete.js:6627:30)
    at doRun (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gmp.js/complete.js:6681:60)
    at run (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gmp.js/complete.js:6695:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/gmp.js/complete.js:6769:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can give more information.
```

Comment: If you need just slightly better precision of float number you can use [double.js](https://github.com/munrocket/double.js) or [bigfloat](https://github.com/charto/bigfloat) libraries. Maybe you don't need to compile c++ to js.

Comment: My use case is a very deep Mandelbrot zoom, so slightly better precision falls short after a few iterations. Also, I need the native speed provided by compiled libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out to do it, you need to be using a 32 bit machine. I had a 64 bit machine so I chroot'ed into a 32 bit filesystem using [this tutorial.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_bundled_32-bit_system_in_64-bit_system)

After that, everything worked well. I was making a Mandelbrot program using GMP and MPFR, and I posted the compiling script (along with the program itself) online on GitHub. [Here](https://github.com/Flarp/Distri-Mandelbrot/blob/master/configure) it is. Adapt it for your own projects.

Answer (score 10):

These instructions are for a host running amd64 Debian Buster.  It seems that GMP no longer needs 32bit to work with Emscripten (and in any case 32bit Emscripten seems no longer supported?), but I used a chroot for clean environment.  After installing, my chroot was 1.6GB large.  But I wouldn't recommend using it for compute-intensive code if you can avoid it, in one benchmark my native code was 15 times faster than the same code compiled with Emscripten running in nodejs...

### Debian Buster chroot

```
mkdir emscripten
sudo debootstrap buster emscripten
sudo chroot emscripten /bin/bash
echo "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update
apt install python cmake g++ git lzip wget nodejs m4
echo "none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount /dev/shm
echo "none /proc proc defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount /proc
adduser emscripten
su - emscripten
```

### emsdk latest

At time of writing this installed
`releases-upstream-b024b71038d1291ed7ec23ecd553bf2c0c8d6da6-64bit`
and `node-12.9.1-64bit`:

```
git clone https://github.com/juj/emsdk.git
cd emsdk
./emsdk install latest
./emsdk activate latest
source ./emsdk_env.sh
mkdir -p ${HOME}/opt/src
cd ${HOME}/opt/src
```

### gmp 6.1.2

```
wget https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/gmp-6.1.2.tar.lz
tar xf gmp-6.1.2.tar.lz
cd gmp-6.1.2
emconfigure ./configure --disable-assembly --host none --enable-cxx --prefix=${HOME}/opt
make
make install
cd ..
```

### mpfr 4.0.2

```
wget https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr-4.0.2.tar.xz
wget https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/allpatches
tar xf mpfr-4.0.2.tar.xz
cd mpfr-4.0.2
patch -N -Z -p1 < ../allpatches 
emconfigure ./configure --host none --prefix=${HOME}/opt --with-gmp=${HOME}/opt
make
make install
cd ..
```

### mpc 1.1.0

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpc/mpc-1.1.0.tar.gz
tar xf mpc-1.1.0.tar.gz
cd mpc-1.1.0
emconfigure ./configure --host none --prefix=${HOME}/opt --with-gmp=${HOME}/opt --with-mpfr=${HOME}/opt
make
make install
cd ..
```

### hello world

Your favourite program using GMP/MPFR/MPC:

```
emcc -o hello.js hello.c \
  ${HOME}/opt/lib/libmpc.a ${HOME}/opt/lib/libmpfr.a ${HOME}/opt/lib/libgmp.a
nodejs hello.js
```

Comment: My men !
All your stuff work, incredible.
Just add `-I${HOME}/opt/include` in the emcc command and all work as expected, thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

I packaged it into a NPM library called [gmp-wasm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmp-wasm). You can find a Dockerized code which builds the library within the [source](https://github.com/Daninet/gmp-wasm/tree/master/binding). It exports both low-level functions and an immutable high-level wrapper:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gmp-wasm"></script>
<script>
  gmp.init().then(({
    calculate
  }) => {
    // calculate() automatically deallocates all objects
    // created within the callback function
    const result = calculate((g) => {
      const six = g.Float(1).add(5);
      const res = g.Pi().div(six).sin();
      return res;
    });
    document.write(`sin(Pi/6) = ` + result);
  });
</script>
```

Using low-level functions:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gmp-wasm"></script>
<script>
  gmp.init().then(({
    calculate, binding
  }) => {
    const result = calculate((g) => {
      const a = g.Float(1);
      const b = g.Float(2);
      const c = g.Float(0);
      // c = a + b
      binding.mpfr_add(c.mpfr_t, a.mpfr_t, b.mpfr_t, 0);
      return c;
    });
    document.write(`1 + 2 = ` + result);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: An asynchronous MATH library? Why??