# What value should host be when compiling to WASM?

Tags: cross-compiling, webassembly, configure, emscripten, autoconf

I'm building a library that has a configure file. When using `emconfigure`, what value should be specified for the host switch so that it compiles for WebAssembly? For example `emconfigure ./configure --host none -O3`. I've looked but can't find the documentation for this.

Comment: Can you just not set any value?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if no value is given for host, `emconfigure` fails with `checking for assembler label suffix... configure: error: Cannot determine label suffix`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41080815/2752075) suggests `--host none --disable-assembly`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that does technically work but I'm wondering if there's a better option in terms of optimization? Also some explanation would be nice.

Comment: I mean, you can probably still add `-O3`. Regarding custom assembly, which I assume `--disable-assembly` disables, if there actually was custom assembly for WASM, it would probably work out of the box.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat should `-flto` be passed for enabling link time optimization? When is this useful?

Comment: I think emscripten's `-O3` does it by default? In any case, this is a separate issue (optimizing the code as opposed to fixing `configure` errors), and should be asked in a separate question.